# Focus problems with JDK7 and native components

Tags: java, swing, java-native-interface, java-7, jxbrowser

We have a swing application which embeds a IE ocx component via JNIWrapper.

After switching from jdk6 to jdk7 we start noticing focus problems. When the embedded IE shows a web page with text fields (e.g. the google search page) than the trouble starts:

The Browser 'catches' the focus, so u can start typing in the search text field. Every key typed goes to the IE ocx. But swing seems to ignore this focus change. Even if i change the focus to a swing text field (and swing shows the blinking input cursor), all typed keys goes to the IE ocx

The only way to 'fix' the focus is to deacitvate and activate the main frame. after that the focus seems to be consistent. But if i click in the google search text field again, the focus is broken again.

It seems there is a big change to focus handling in jdk7. From the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/awt.html):

> On the Windows platform, a concept of “synthetic focus” has been implemented. It means that a focus owner component only emulates its focusable state whereas real native focus is set to a “focus proxy” component. This component receives key and input method native messages and dispatches them to a focus owner. Prior to JDK7 a focus proxy component was a dedicated hidden child component inside a frame/dialog. In JDK7 a frame/dialog itself serves as a focus proxy. Now it proxies focus not only for components in an owned window but for all child components as well. A simple window never receives native focus and relies on focus proxy of its owner. This mechanism is transparent for a user but should be taken into account when debugging.

Anyone has an idea to 'fix' the behavior?

*EDIT*: Here some code to reproduce the problem with [JxBrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Browser browser = BrowserFactory.createBrowser(BrowserType.IE);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(browser.getComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    textField = new JTextField();
    panel.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
    frame.setSize(700, 500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    browser.navigate("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: maybe I'm wrong, but this is issue with FocusRecycle implemented in Native OS, please how to handle your wrapper with Focus, toFront, basically Java doesn't care about Mouse & Key events without Focusable

Comment: we could reproduce the problem with using a swing panel containing a JTextField and a jxbrowser (http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/).

Comment: The issue is only present when the wmode of the flash object is not window,

Answer (score 3):

All - We just experienced this problem with another browser component (DjProject Native Swing). Everything works fine under Java 1.6 but under Java-7 we started seeing weird problems where you can type into an input box but if you select backwards to fix a typo you could not type after making the mouse click. To recover you had to select out of the input field and then back in to continue your edit.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/awt.html#gdcqp
Particularly the part here about sythentic focus and focus proxies.

Anyway to cut a long story short - in our case I was able to find a work-around by attaching a mouse listener to the JWebBrowser.getNativeComponent(). Then on mousePressed execute a browser.requestFocus() followed by a browser.getNativeComponent().requestFocusInWindow();

Hope this helps anyone else that comes across this.

Comment: I was able to make it work after I did the following: compile with JDK 1.6, run with JRE 1.6 and downgraded swt libraries to 3.8. The last piece was the only change that made it work. I was using 4.x before and still seeing the issue even when compiling/running on Java 1.6

Comment: The above comment is invalid since is broken when ran on Java 7, or Java 8 for that matter. See my answer below.

Comment: According to your description, it matches this SWT bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353683

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [FocusListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html) and [WindowFocusListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowFocusListener.html) to implement the listeners for either the Swing components themselves or the JFrame.  Whenever a call is made to `focusLost(..)` it you can use `requestFocus()` on the Window or Component to force the focus to return.

Comment: I don't get any feedback with this options.

Comment: What kind of feedback are you referring to?

Comment: If I out an output I never see it. In our case the component wmode is opaque, so is a heavyweight component. Sadly changing to window is not an option.

Comment: Being opaque has nothing to do with being a heavyweight component.

Comment: Maybe, but at least seems to make a difference in this issue.

Comment: Are you using Frame or JFrame?

Comment: JFrame. Does it make a difference?

Comment: No.  But you can add a FocusListener or WindowFocusListener on a JFrame.  So this method will work just fine.

Comment: I tried it, but I can't capture the events. Printing dummy messages to console shows nothing.

Comment: I was able to make it work after I did the following: compile with JDK 1.6, run with JRE 1.6 and downgraded swt libraries to 3.8. The last piece was the only change that made it work. I was using 4.x before and still seeing the issue even when compiling/running on Java 1.6

Comment: Ah you are using SWT.  That could cause issues.  So it's working with 3.8?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a working workaround. During figuring out what was causing this it was noticed that clicking on another component (i.e. a JLabel) and clicking back on the text field worked fine. So I replicated that behavior using AWT Robot class. See more details in [Replicating Mouse behavior in Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742540/replicating-mouse-behavior-in-code/16842951#16842951).

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest jdk of Java 1.7. It worked for me.
Earlier, I was not able to enter any input in the text fields. After upgrading, I do not face that problem.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8018672