# Replicating Mouse behavior in Code

Tags: java, windows, focus, swt, java-7

This is related to question: [Focus problems with JDK7 and native components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230006/focus-problems-with-jdk7-and-native-components).

While working on workarounds we noticed that if we clicked on another component on the window (i.e. a label showing a picture) and then click on the text fields (within the Flash application), everything seemed to work fine. So I've been trying to reproduce that from code but haven't been successful.

Basically, when the mouse is detected hovering over the text box I get notified from the Flash program and I request focus on the label, so when the user clicks on the actual field the label already has the focus.

I request focus like this:

```
draggableComponent.requestFocus();
```

Where draggableComponent is the label I've been talking about. I guess this is not equivalent to clicking on the label. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer [here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt/simulating-mouse-and-key-presses.html).

The following example shows how to simulate mouse and key presses in Java using java.awt.Robot class.

```
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    // Simulate a mouse click
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

    // Simulate a key press
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class gave me everything I needed.